# discord.js random video bot adds token to ends of video name

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Compiled this simple script to send a random video to use when he asks and it does but the problem is when I use streamable link it adds a token after .mp4
So how can I make it cut everything after the token and send the file?

I tried to cut the token and it just sends a link I tried to upload to other services and it does the same.
I can't upload this locally since I'm hosting on glitch.com
Any help would be appreciated.

```
//nyan dance//
const nyan_dance = [
'https://cdn-b-east.streamable.com/video/mp4/pepek.mp4token=FrRv_gQneT012mzlC7dRCA&expires=570819200',
]
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content.includes("dance nyan!")) {
    msg.channel.send("here we go", {
    file: nyan_dance[Math.floor(Math.random() * nyan_dance.length)]
});
  }
});
```

I want it to does what it does but cut the token in the file name after .mp4 and upload it and i'm sorry if this is a dumb question I'm not a coder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to accomplish this, for example:

```
/token.+/
```

Here is a breakdown of how it works:

```
/
  token //matches the literal word "token"
  .+    //matches 1 or more characters of any kind
/
```

We can apply it to your example by using the `replace` method:

```js
//nyan dance//
const nyan_dance = [
'https://cdn-b-east.streamable.com/video/mp4/pepek.mp4token=FrRv_gQneT012mzlC7dRCA&expires=570819200',
]
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content.includes("dance nyan!")) {
    msg.channel.send("here we go", {
      file: nyan_dance[Math.floor(Math.random() * nyan_dance.length)].replace(/token.+/, "")
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry about bothering ya but it says in the Console that
TypeError: Math.floor(...).replace is not a function am I doing something wrong? 
Sorry again I'm not a coder

Comment: I'm so sorry, I mistakenly put the replace function after the Math.floor function, instead of making it apply to the Element picked in the Array. I edited my answer. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Thank you for the fix again and I hope it don't bother you but now it saying "Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block" I googled it and tried to come up with a solution and no one seems to have the right answer or one that I understand could you please help me? and thank you and I'm so so sorry to bother you about something so simple.

Comment: This happens when a promise calls it's `reject` function. A simple fix is to just catch the rejection by doing `.catch((error) => console.error(error));` after the promise call.

Comment: The rejection seems to be caused by the fact that you use `file` instead of `files`, simply change your message sending code to this: `msg.channel.send("here we go", {files: [nyan_dance[Math.floor(Math.random() * nyan_dance.length)].replace(/token.+/, "")]});`